# Cant get into Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, console

Cant get into Firebase console. it is loading and loading for a long time. I have tried different browsers, enabled, disabled some extensions recommended by some people but couldn't do anything.Still didn't find any authentic solution.

Comment: You should contact firebase support for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just try and clear the browser cache and retry to login to the firebase console.

Look if JavaScript is enabled to access by the firebase website under permissions.

One another thing you can try is that you can download firebase cli tools using npm and try and login using command line using firebase tools.